# Outlook express and IMAP: are there advantages?

Tags: imap, pop3, outlook

I am going to configure email accounts in Outlook Express from POP3 to IMAP protocoll, becouse I would like avoid the problems when the file .dbx have their dimension is over 2 gigabytes. What's your opinion about?

Comment: doesn't look like a programming question, might be better suited to superuser or serverfault perhaps?

Comment: Depends on whether it's asked from an end-user or admin perspective I guess.

Answer (score 0):

File size limits are quite honestly the least significant reason to switch.

The main benefit you'll see out of IMAP is that multiple mail clients/machines can all be pointed at the same mailbox and not have to go through odd gyrations like "leave mail on server for 3 days" to avoid the problem of some machines missing messages, or having to delete annoying junk from every machine separately.

You may also get some side benefits; more advanced IMAP implementations support server push, but not all clients can make effective use of it.

On the down side, the IMAP specification has some issues, so not all combinations of client and server software will work together.